# Why does this production code work: `base64.b64decode(api_token.encode(“utf-8)).decode(“utf-8”)`?

Tags: python, python-2.7, airflow

Today at work, I saw the following line of code:

`decoded_token = base64.b64decode(api_token.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")`

It is part of an AirFlow ETL script and `decoded_token` is used as a Bearer Token in an API request. This code is executed on a server that uses Python 2.7 and my coworker told my that this code runs daily, successfully.

Yet, from my understanding, the code first tries to turn `api_token` into bytes (.encode), then turn the bytes into a string (base64.b64decode) and finally turn the string again into a string (.decode). I would think that this always leads to an error.

```py
import base64
api_token = "random-string"
decoded_token = base64.b64decode(api_token.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")
```

Running the code locally gives me:

Error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 0: invalid start byte`

What input/type would `api_token` need to be in order for this line *not* to throw an error? Is that even possible or must there be something else at play?

**Edit:** As mentioned by Klaus D., apparently, in Python 2 both `encode` and `decode` consumed and returned a string. Yet, running the code above in Python 2.7 gives me the same error and I have yet to find an input for `api_token` that does not throw an error.

Comment: for this case, you need to `.b64encode()` before decoding as it's not base64 (yet), while your incoming string may not need this .. you may need to `.encode()` too (without `"utf-8"`) as the string already knows its encoding (woops, may additionally only apply to Python 3.x)

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, this is not my code but supposedly code that works fine in production and I don't understand how it can...

Comment: In Python 2 there were no bytes. Both `encode()` and `decode()` were `str` → `str`.

Comment: @Klaus In Python 2 it was `str` <-> `unicode`…!?

Comment: @KlausD. Didn't they add a `bytes` type in Python 2.7 that's just an alias for `str`?

Comment: `api_token` appears to be expected to be a *base 64 encoded string.*

Comment: @deceze: Ahh, you're right! Thank you - I somehow missed that... And `base64.b64decode` returns Unicode which is then turned into a regular string by `.decode("utf-8")`, correct? (P.S.: Seems like a good idea for me to read your latest blog article :-))

Comment: @MarkRansom True. Now I remember how it freaked out a college on a Python 2 → 3 migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely just that your test input string is not a base64-encoded string, while in production, whatever input already is!

```py
Python 2.7.18 (default, Jan  4 2022, 17:47:56)
...
>>> import base64
>>> api_token = "random-string"
>>> base64.b64decode(api_token)
'\xad\xa9\xdd\xa2k-\xae)\xe0'
>>> base64.b64decode(api_token).decode("utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 0: invalid start byte
```

encoding the string as base64, you also don't need to decode it as "utf-8" afterwards, though you may if you expect unicode characters

```py
>>> api_token = base64.b64encode(api_token)
>>> api_token
'cmFuZG9tLXN0cmluZw=='
>>> base64.b64decode(api_token)
'random-string'
>>> base64.b64decode(api_token).decode("utf-8")
u'random-string'
```

Example with non-ascii characters

```py
>>> base64.b64decode(base64.b64encode("random string后缀"))
'random string\xe5\x90\x8e\xe7\xbc\x80'
>>> base64.b64decode(base64.b64encode("random string后缀")).decode("utf-8")
u'random string\u540e\u7f00'
>>> sys.stdout.write(base64.b64decode(base64.b64encode("random string后缀")) + "\n")
random string后缀
```

Note that in Python 2.7, `bytes` is just an alias for `str`, and a special `unicode` was added to support unicode!

```py
>>> bytes is str
True
>>> bytes is unicode
False
>>> str("foo")
'foo'
>>> unicode("foo")
u'foo'
```

Comment: I think the ancient saying "Garbage in, garbage out" applies perfectly here.